# deleting some undesirable rows

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file like as below and I want to delete the rows that don't have any value in the fourth column.

```
Experiment Replica Module Mean
General1 0 scenario.host[229].app  
General1 1 scenario.host[229].app 0.00235355 
General1 2 scenario.host[229].app  
General1 3 scenario.host[229].app 0.0783413 
General1 4 scenario.host[229].app  
General3 0 scenario.host[229].app  
General3 1 scenario.host[229].app 0.540335 
General3 2 scenario.host[229].app  
General3 3 scenario.host[229].app  
General3 4 scenario.host[229].app  
General1 0 scenario.host[229].app
```

Comment: Are you looking for something as simple as `grep -v .app$ file`?

Comment: Including the row with the headers?

Comment: Whenever you find yourself writing requirements in negative terms (e.g. "I want to **delet** the rows that **doesn't have**...") take a second to see if you can express that in a positive way (e.g. "I want to **select** the rows that **have**...") and you'll usually find it easier to come up with a good solution and avoid the risk of introducing double negatives which make comprehension far more difficult.

Comment: @EdMorton May I suggest editing this into your answer? This is too important and helpful to get lost in tinyfontcommentspace.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
awk 'NF>3' file
```

EDIT: Added per @AdrianFrühwirth's request:

Whenever you find yourself writing requirements in negative terms (e.g. "I want to **delet** the rows that **doesn't have**...") take a second to see if you can express that in a positive way (e.g. "I want to **select** the rows that **have**...") and you'll usually find it easier to come up with a good solution and avoid the risk of introducing double negatives which make comprehension far more difficult.